# Submit form without page reloading

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, forms

I have a classifieds website, and on the page where ads are showed, I am creating a "Send a tip to a friend" form...

So anybody who wants can send a tip of the ad to some friends email-adress.

I am guessing the form must be submitted to a php page right?

```html
<form name="tip" method="post" action="tip.php">
  Tip somebody: 
  <input 
    name="tip_email"
    type="text" 
    size="30" 
    onfocus="tip_div(1);" 
    onblur="tip_div(2);"
  />
  <input type="submit" value="Skicka Tips" />
  <input type="hidden" name="ad_id" />
</form>
```

When submitting the form, the page gets reloaded... I don't want that...

Is there any way to make it not reload and still send the mail?
Preferrably without ajax or jquery...

Comment: To send a form you must make an HTTP request, making HTTP requests without loading the page is what Ajax means. Might as well try to drive to town without a vehicle.

Comment: "without ajax or jquery" sounds like "I want a car without wheels"

Comment: @Keith Almost, `<iframe>` and the `target` attribute will do it.

Comment: You aren't using XmlHttpRequest specifically, but you are still calling the server asynchronously with javascript. That falls under Ajax.

Comment: I read the title and thought "Ah, he just need Ajax". I was reading the question further while nipping my coffee and preparing an answer in my head. At end of the question my coffee is all over the screen...

Comment: @BalusC: I completely agree. It boggles my mind that people are still afraid of using Ajax and 3rd party js libs these days

Comment: @Keith The way I mentioned did not use JavaScript, so I guess you could call it *Ax* (Asynchronous XHTML) or something... :P http://jsbin.com/upize/edit

Comment: Use the following jQuery plugin to achieve this :https://github.com/jinujd/jQuery-Async-Form

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18169933/submit-form-without-reloading-page. It was closed for being a duplicate, but offers some other useful examples.

Comment: See also modern approach to data exchange: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29775797/fetch-post-json-data

Answer (score 84, accepted):

> **Editor's Note**: This answer was historically accepted as correct, but is now outdated. While the code still works, if your target browser(s) support the [FormData](https://caniuse.com/mdn-api_formdata) and [Fetch](https://caniuse.com/fetch) APIs (ie. nearly all modern browsers), consider checking out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73915781) instead.

You'll need to submit an AJAX request to send the email without reloading the page. Take a look at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Your code should be something along the lines of:

```
$('#submit').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'send_email.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            email: 'email@example.com',
            message: 'hello world!'
        },
        success: function(msg) {
            alert('Email Sent');
        }               
    });
});
```

The form will submit in the background to the `send_email.php` page which will need to handle the request and send the email.

Comment: How would this look like if you included the HTML as well?

Comment: How would you do this with just vanilla AJAX with mere JavaScript?

Comment: .ajax not a function error with almost same of your solution used. https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/GnHzY84DQ3/

Comment: If the form is still refreshing, add `return false;` before the last closing brackets

Comment: This answer requires a jquery dependency. A modern solution in 2020 is to use XMLHttpRequest as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18169995/2225804).

Comment: It's not 2010 anymore, you can use newer APIs: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/73915781](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73915781)

Comment: @user2225804 `XMLHttpRequest` is not modern in any way.

Comment: @Unmitigated The point is that the accepted answer requires jquery. It's common these days to use plain Javascript. Hard to say three years later why I didn't mention fetch- maybe because it wasn't supported by node at that time. Setting that aside, I don't think it's controversial to suggest a non-jquery solution today.

Answer (score 118):

If you put an iframe in the page, you can redirect the response there using the form's `target` attribute. If you don't want the response to show up at all, you can set the iframe's display to none.

```html
<iframe name="votar" style="display:none;"></iframe>
<form action="tip.php" method="post" target="votar">
    <input type="submit" value="Skicka Tips">
    <input type="hidden" name="ad_id" value="2">            
</form>
```

Comment: I used `action="about:blank"`

Comment: With this, can you still grab the values such as: `$_POST["ad_id"]`

Comment: Unfortunately this solution won't work for me because submitting the form causes the javascript to run again and the document-ready event is invoked.

Comment: This looks like a very good answer. But with this approach it would be impossible to handle different error codes and validation errors. But for creating some example code for someone, this could come in handy.

Answer (score 24):

Fastest and easiest way is to use an iframe.
Put a frame at the bottom of your page.

`<iframe name="frame"></iframe>`

And in your form do this.

```
<form target="frame">
</form>
```

and to make the frame invisible in your css.

```
iframe{
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: I suggest to call the css by id or class.

Answer (score 21):

You either use AJAX or you

- create and append an iframe to the document
- set the iframes name to 'foo'
- set the forms target to 'foo'
- submit
- have the forms action render javascript with 'parent.notify(...)' to give feedback
- optionally you can remove the iframe

Comment: That's still Ajax. Not XHR, but still Ajax.

Comment: great trick thank you. sample for usage `<form id="myGiswebForm" method="post" action="https://******/saveForm.asp" target="myiframe">` and `<iframe style="display:none;" src="" name="myiframe"></iframe>`

Answer (score 17):

##### SUBMITTING THE FORM WITHOUT RELOADING THE PAGE AND GET THE RESULT OF SUBMITTED DATA ON THE SAME PAGE.

Here's some of the code I found on the internet that solves this problem :

### 1.) **IFRAME**

When the form is submitted, The action will be executed and target the specific iframe to reload.

### index.php

```
<iframe name="content" style="">
</iframe>
<form action="iframe_content.php" method="post" target="content">
<input type="text" name="Name" value="">
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

### iframe_content.php

```
<?php
$Submit = isset($_POST['Submit']) ? $_POST['Submit'] : false;
$Name = isset($_POST['Name']) ? $_POST['Name'] : '';
if($Submit){
 echo $Name;
}
?>
```

### 2.) **AJAX**

### Index.php:

```
<form >
    <input type="" name="name" id="name">
    <input type="" name="descr" id="descr">
    <input type="submit" name="" value="submit" onclick="return clickButton();">
</form>
<p id="msg"></p>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function clickButton(){
    var name=document.getElementById('name').value;
    var descr=document.getElementById('descr').value;
    $.ajax({
        type:"post",
        url:"server_action.php",
        data: 
        {  
           'name' :name,
           'descr' :descr
        },
        cache:false,
        success: function (html) 
        {
           alert('Data Send');
           $('#msg').html(html);
        }
    });
    return false;
 }
</script>
```

### server_action.php

```
<?php 
$name = isset($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] : '';
$descr = isset($_POST['descr']) ? $_POST['descr'] : '';


echo $name;
echo $descr;

?>
```

**Tags:** [php](/questions/tagged/php)[ajax](/questions/tagged/ajax)[jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery)[serverside](/questions/tagged/serverside)[html](/questions/tagged/html)

Comment: I have searched a lot times on internet.
I was using Jquery, but  Jquery sometimes works and sometimes not,
So i think ajax is best that is mention in your answer.

Answer (score 12):

#### Modern Answer without XHR or jQuery

It's 2022, we don't need to use old tools like XHR or jQuery when we have the [Fetch API](https://caniuse.com/mdn-api_fetch) and the [FormData API](https://caniuse.com/mdn-api_formdata)!

The first thing we need to do is prevent the default form submission behavior from occurring with `event.preventDefault()`:

```js
form.addEventListener("submit", function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    // ...
});
```

Now we need to replace the submission behavior with our own AJAX request. The Fetch API makes it pretty simple to post form data - just create a new [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData) object, populating it with the form's values, and use it as the body of a fetch request:

```js
fetch(form.action, {
    method: "post",
    body: new FormData(form)
});
```

Note that this submits an HTTP request using the `multipart/form-data` encoding type. If you need to post the data using the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` format, create a new [`URLSearchParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) object from the `FormData` object and use that as the fetch's body.<sup>1</sup>

```js
fetch(form.action, {
    method: "post",
    body: new URLSearchParams(new FormData(form))
});
```

Finally, if you instead want to submit the HTTP request as JSON, use the following:<sup>2</sup>

```js
fetch(form.action, {
    method: "post",
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(Object.fromEntries(new FormData(form)))
});
```

Here's a full code example:

```js
let form = document.querySelector("form");

form.addEventListener("submit", function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
  
    fetch(form.action, {
        method: "post",
        body: new URLSearchParams(new FormData(form)) // for application/x-www-form-urlencoded
        // body: new FormData(form) // for multipart/form-data
    });
});
```

```html
<form method="POST">
  <input name="name" placeholder="Name" />
  <input name="phone" type="tel" placeholder="Phone" />
  <input name="email" type="email" placeholder="Email" />
  <input name="submit" type="submit" />
</form>
```

---

<sup>1</sup> [What's the difference between `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and `multipart/form-data`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007969/application-x-www-form-urlencoded-or-multipart-form-data)

<sup>2</sup> Code based on [this answer to "How to convert FormData (HTML5 object) to JSON"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55874235/7941251). Note that if a key is duplicated, only the last value is used.

Comment: Worked out perfectly! Very useful modern trick, especially with usage of `new URLSearchParams()` which is required to get same behavior as with normal submission, but is far not obvious.

Answer (score 7):

A further possibility is to make a direct javascript link to your function:

```
<form action="javascript:your_function();" method="post">
```

...

Comment: Can't believe such a simple solution actually worked, deserves far more upvotes.

Answer (score 5):

It's a must to take help of `jquery-ajax` in this case. Without `ajax`, there is currently no solution.

First, call a JavaScript function when the form is submitted. Just set `onsubmit="func()"`. Even if the function is called, the default action of the submission would be performed. If it is performed there would be no way of stoping the page from refreshing or redirecting. So, next task is to prevent the default action. Insert the following line at the start of `func()`.

```
event.preventDefault()
```

Now, there will be no redirecting or refreshing. So, you simply make an ajax call from `func()` and do whatever you want to do when call ends.

**Example:**

Form:

```
<form id="form-id" onsubmit="func()">
    <input id="input-id" type="text">
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
function func(){
    event.preventDefault();
    var newValue = $('#input-field-id').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '...',
        data: {...},
        datatype: 'JSON',
        success: function(data){...},
        error: function(){...},
    });
}
```

Answer (score 4):

this is exactly how it CAN work without jQuery and AJAX and it's working very well using a simple iFrame. I LOVE IT, works in Opera10, FF3 and IE6. Thanks to some of the above posters pointing me the right direction, that's the only reason I am posting here:

```
<select name="aAddToPage[65654]" 
onchange="
    if (bCanAddMore) {
        addToPage(65654,this);
    }
    else {
        alert('Could not add another, wait until previous is added.'); 
        this.options[0].selected = true;
    };
" />
<option value="">Add to page..</option>
[more options with values here]</select>

<script type="text/javascript">
function addToPage(iProduct, oSelect){
    iPage = oSelect.options[oSelect.selectedIndex].value;
    if (iPage != "") {
        bCanAddMore = false;
        window.hiddenFrame.document.formFrame.iProduct.value = iProduct;
        window.hiddenFrame.document.formFrame.iAddToPage.value = iPage;
        window.hiddenFrame.document.formFrame.submit();
    }
}
var bCanAddMore = true;</script> 

<iframe name="hiddenFrame" style="display:none;" src="frame.php?p=addProductToPage" onload="bCanAddMore = true;"></iframe>
```

the php code generating the page that is being called above:

```
if( $_GET['p'] == 'addProductToPage' ){  // hidden form processing
  if(!empty($_POST['iAddToPage'])) {
    //.. do something with it.. 
  }
  print('
    <html>
        <body>
            <form name="formFrame" id="formFrameId" style="display:none;" method="POST" action="frame.php?p=addProductToPage" >
                <input type="hidden" name="iProduct" value="" />
                <input type="hidden" name="iAddToPage" value="" />
            </form>
        </body>
    </html>
  ');
}
```

Comment: Don't use PHP `print` to print HTML code. Just close php tag `?>` and add the html code after. And avoid using `exit` it it isn't necessary (fatal errors, ...)

Comment: yeah, thanks for pointing it out. This is just a necessary example, I don't really have it done this way in my system.

Comment: That's a lot of work on this answer, but there are many others.

Comment: the only side issue to this is the get() in it because I wouldn't want the form state book markable/cacheable.

Answer (score 4):

This should solve your problem.
In this code after submit button click we call jquery ajax and we pass url to post
type POST/GET
data: data information you can select input fields or any other.
sucess: callback if everything is ok from server
function parameter text, html or json, response from server 
in sucess you can write write warnings if data you got is in some kind of state and so on. or execute your code what to do next.

```
<form id='tip'>
Tip somebody: <input name="tip_email" id="tip_email" type="text" size="30" onfocus="tip_div(1);" onblur="tip_div(2);"/>
 <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Skicka Tips"/>
 <input type="hidden" id="ad_id" name="ad_id" />
 </form>
<script>
$( "#tip" ).submit(function( e ) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: tip.php,
        type:'POST',
        data:
        {
            tip_email: $('#tip_email').val(),
            ad_id: $('#ad_id').val()
        },
        success: function(msg)
        {

            alert('Email Sent');
        }               
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try setting the target attribute of your form to a hidden iframe, so the page containing the form won't get reloaded.

I tried it with file uploads (which we know can't be done via AJAX), and it worked beautifully.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using an iFrame? No ajax, and the original page will not load.

You can display the submit form as a separate page inside the iframe, and when it gets submitted the outer/container page will not reload. This solution will not make use of any kind of ajax.

Answer (score 1):

```
function Foo(){  
   event.preventDefault(); 
 $.ajax(   {  
      url:"<?php echo base_url();?>Controllername/ctlr_function",
      type:"POST",
      data:'email='+$("#email").val(),
      success:function(msg)      {  
         alert('You are subscribed');
      }
   }   );
}
```

I tried many times for a good solution and answer by @taufique helped me to arrive at this answer.

**NB** : Don't forget to put    `event.preventDefault();`  at the beginning of the body of the function .

Answer (score 1):

I did something similar to the jquery above, but I needed to reset my form data and graphic attachment canvases.
So here is what I came up with:

```
    <script>
   $(document).ready(function(){

   $("#text_only_radio_button_id").click(function(){
       $("#single_pic_div").hide();
       $("#multi_pic_div").hide();
   });

   $("#pic_radio_button_id").click(function(){
      $("#single_pic_div").show();
      $("#multi_pic_div").hide();
    });

   $("#gallery_radio_button_id").click(function(){
       $("#single_pic_div").hide();
       $("#multi_pic_div").show();
                 });
    $("#my_Submit_button_ID").click(function() {
          $("#single_pic_div").hide();
          $("#multi_pic_div").hide();
          var url = "script_the_form_gets_posted_to.php"; 

       $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: url,
       data: $("#html_form_id").serialize(), 
       success: function(){  
       document.getElementById("html_form_id").reset();
           var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var canvasA=document.getElementById("canvasA");
    var canvasB=document.getElementById("canvasB");
    var canvasC=document.getElementById("canvasC");
    var canvasD=document.getElementById("canvasD");

              var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
              var ctxA=canvasA.getContext("2d");
              var ctxB=canvasB.getContext("2d");
              var ctxC=canvasC.getContext("2d");
              var ctxD=canvasD.getContext("2d");
               ctx.clearRect(0, 0,480,480);
               ctxA.clearRect(0, 0,480,480);
               ctxB.clearRect(0, 0,480,480);        
               ctxC.clearRect(0, 0,480,480);
               ctxD.clearRect(0, 0,480,480);
               } });
           return false;
                });    });
           </script>
```

That works well for me, for your application of just an html form, we can simplify this jquery code like this:

```
       <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){

    $("#my_Submit_button_ID").click(function() {
        var url =  "script_the_form_gets_posted_to.php";
       $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: url,
       data: $("#html_form_id").serialize(), 
       success: function(){  
       document.getElementById("html_form_id").reset();
            } });
           return false;
                });    });
           </script>
```

Answer (score -1):

The page will get reloaded if you don't want to use javascript

Comment: ...or do something ugly like a `<iframe name="ew" />` and `<form target="ew" />`

Comment: They never said no JS, but rather "Preferrably without ajax or jquery"

Answer (score -1):

I don't know JavaScript and I just started to learn PHP, so what helped for me from all those responses was:

1. Create inedx.php and insert:

```
<iframe name="email" style=""></iframe>
<form action="email.php" method="post" target="email">
<input type="email" name="email" >
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

2. Create email.php and insert this code to check if you are getting the data (you should see it on index.php in the iframe):

```
    <?php
    if (isset($_POST['Submit'])){
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    echo $email;
    }
    ?>
```

3. If everything is ok, change the code on email.php to:

```
    <?php
    if (isset($_POST['Submit'])){
    $to = $_POST['email'];
    $subject = "Test email";
    $message = "Test message";
    $headers = "From: test@test.com \r\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: test@test.com \r\n";
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
    
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
    }
    ?>
```

Hope this helps for all other rookies like me :)

Answer (score -5):

Here is some jQuery for posting to a php page and getting html back:

```
$('form').submit(function() {
    $.post('tip.php', function(html) {
       // do what you need in your success callback
    }
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Care to explain why you downvoted? You can't do it without Ajax

Comment: @Keith No downvote from me, but maybe it was because you mentioned jQuery and he said no jQuery.

Comment: @Keith - on the contrary, the iframe method suggested by several answers can be used.

Comment: Those are the wrong arguments for the post method, you aren't collecting any data from the form, and you use a generic "applies to all forms" selector with a "posts to a specific uri instead of getting the action from the form" post call.

Comment: @David - it's a basic example, that is a valid post call and there is only 1 form on the page.

Comment: It isn't. The second argument should not be the callback.

Comment: Oh, good grief. jQuery does type checking so arguments can be skipped. Yuck.

Comment: Yes, they do that all over the place. Welcome to the jQuery API