# Uploading file in a form without page refresh

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, forms

I have this bit of code:

```
<form name="myUploadForm" method="post" action="/scripts/upload.do" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="fileUpload">
   <table width="100%" border="0"> 
      <tr>
         <td>
            <input type="file" name="xlsFile" size="60" value="test.xls"> 
            <input type="button" value="Upload File" name="upload_xls">
         </td>
      </tr>
   </table>
</form>
```

Right now I can upload the file with Struts but it refreshes the page.  How do I do this without the page refreshing?

Comment: possible dupe [ajax - How can I upload files asynchronously with JQuery? - Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously-with-jquery)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Submit form without page reloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2866063/submit-form-without-page-reloading)

Answer (score 6):

What worked for me:

On the form tag, I have target="hidden-iframe"

the hidden i-frame on the page looks like this:

```
<iframe name="hidden-iframe" style="display: none;"></iframe>
```

The important thing to underline here is that the form is referencing the *name* attribute of the frame and not the *id*.

Comment: @FlorianB that blog is dated 2008. (And, I know, your comment is dated 2016!)

Answer (score 5):

You can post form with jQuery and get the result back.

```js
$('#formId' ).submit(
    function( e ) {
        $.ajax( {
            url: '/upload',
            type: 'POST',
            data: new FormData( this ),
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            success: function(result){
                console.log(result);
                //$("#div1").html(str);
            }
        } );
        e.preventDefault();
    } 
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="formId" action="/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="title"><br>
        <input type="file" name="upload" multiple="multiple"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Upload">
</form>
<div id="div1">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can use jQuery, you can use something like [jQuery File Upload](https://plugins.jquery.com/blueimp-file-upload/).

Comment: #Town. I get an error when I am visiting that page.

Comment: Thanks @mightycodeNewton, I've updated it to a working link, although I can't vouch for whether the plugin itself still works, last update appears to have been 2014.

Answer (score 1):

There are two methods:

1. HTML5 supports File API.
2. Create a hidden iframe, point the property 'target' of the form to the iframe's id.