# How to prevent page redirection/refresh after form submit, while preserving file input? Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a file upload form as follows:

```
<form id="upload" action="someurl" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <label for="file">Filename:</label>
  <input type="file" name="file" /> 
  <input type="submit" value="submit" />
<form>
```

Problem is that every time I submit the form I will be redirected to the form's action url.

How do I submit this form while still staying on the same page? Using ajax or preventDefault won't work as I will lose the file stream.

Rendy

Comment: Modern browsers allow you to post files in ajax. That's your only alternative. (*edit* no it isn't :)

Comment: How about an action to the page itself?

Comment: Actually I'm wrong - you could target the form to a hidden iframe.

Comment: @Pointy can you please elaborate more? Targeting the form to a hidden iframe sounds interesting. :)

Answer (score 5):

Provided  you have an  `iframe` on your page that's hidden,

```
<iframe id="hidden-iframe"></iframe>
```

then add a `target` to your form:

```
<form id="upload" action="someurl" method="post" target="hidden-iframe" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <label for="file">Filename:</label>
  <input type="file" name="file" /> 
  <input type="submit" value="submit" />
<form>
```

you're done !

Comment: Right - and then in the response page, you can include some JavaScript that performs appropriate updates of the parent page (that is, the page with the form) to indicate success etc.

Comment: I tried with this solution but while request call status will come cancelled. In database record is created with empty data.any suggestions?

Comment: I had to use name="hidden-iframe" instead of id="hidden-iframe" in order to prevent a new tab from also opening. See second answer on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5638529/uploading-file-in-a-form-without-page-refresh)