# After Submitting HTML form how to stop form resubmision when page refresh

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have HTML form and when click submit form data send to same `php` page.But after submitting we refresh the page web browser show re-submission dialog.How it's stop form submitting while page refreshing.

[image]

**My HTML Code: index.php**

```
<form id="cfrm" method="post" action=".">
    <label>If you don't like this colors you can suggest it from here by selecting or copy and paste &nbsp;</label><input class="color" type="text" name="color1" placeholder="Color 1:ex #AAA" required=""/>
    <input class="color" type="text" name="color2" placeholder="Color 1:ex #CFC" required=""/>
    <input type="submit" id="click" value="Set Colors" name="btnSubmit" />
</form>
```

**PHP code(same page) : index.php**

```
<?php
        if (isset($_POST["btnSubmit"])) {
            $c1 = isset($_POST['color1']) ? $_POST['color1'] : '';
            $c2 = isset($_POST['color2']) ? $_POST['color2'] : '';
            //and do some task here
        }
?>
```

Comment: I think the same issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19346762/how-to-prevent-page-redirection-refresh-after-form-submit-while-preserving-file

Comment: My form action is itself.

Comment: Redirect the page to same location using php header location

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
//Your code comes here

//Redirect at the end of process
header('Location: http://www.example.com/redirect.php');
}
?>
```

Answer (score 4):

Pretty simple, there are probably numerous solutions, what I use is after processing the submission on the server side just simply redirect the user to the same page:

```
header("Location: site.com/your-form-page.php");
```

Comment: You could also send a querystring (GET) param along with that in order to show a message.

Answer (score 2):

redirect the page.

```
header('Location: http://www.example.com/');
```