# Why do we put "?" in action = "?"

Tags: html

When I was learning Php with Mysql, I got a problem :

```
<form action="?" method="POST">
    .
    .
    .
</form>
```

Why do we put "?" in the `action` attribute?
**PS:** this form was for inserting text into a database.

Actually, I have an `Index.php` file which is the controller, and 2 files (`form.html.php` and `joke.html.php` as templates). In the tutorial, I first clicked on a link "add joke" to include the `form.html.php` file and in this form there is `<form action="?"> </form>` and a submit `<input>`. When I click on submit, the controller index tests and executes the inserted SQL query.

Thanks.

Comment: "?" is used to form GET variable query strings. This would submit the form (with form-encoded POST data) to the same page it's on but set no variables.

Comment: But in addition to posting to the same URL, it would blank any existing query string...

Comment: Beware the `<base href="...">`.

Comment: Please read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1131781/is-it-a-good-practice-to-use-an-empty-url-for-a-html-forms-action-attribute-a

Comment: Actually , I have an Index.php which is the controller ! and 2 files (form.html.php and joke.html.php as templates) and in the tutorial first I click on a link "add joke" to include the form.html.php and in this form there is this <form action="?"> </form> and a submin <input> and when I click on submit the controller index tests and execute the inserting sql query .

Comment: This has nothing to do with either PHP or MySQL. It is an HTML question.

Comment: In the book he explained it like this way , but I didn't get it :
"instead of leaving the action attribute empty (""), we set its value to ?. As we’ll
see in a moment, the URL used to display the form in this example will feature a
query string, and setting the action to ? strips that query string off the URL when
submitting the form."

Comment: Okay' I understand it now !
I will explain it well :
The main page is printing my jokes in my database (the data are jokes) , Okay!
when I want to add a joke I have to click a link :
<a href="?addjoke"> ... </a>
when I click on it the link will change , and it will be : "localhost/a/?addjoke"
So the form has a textarea with a variable "joketext" where the joke is stored .
the index uses the 
if (isset($_POST['joketext'])) {};
so the $_POST has to find the joketext variable, so that's why the action="?", to strip the link "localhost/a/?addjoke" when submitting the form.

Thank you anyway :)

Comment: This `<a href="?addjoke">` and `isset($_POST['joketext'])` are two different animals altogether. Your `href` demands a GET method and not a POST. Why don't you just post your whole code and let the people decide.

Comment: I don't know, I'm applying the tutorial. Maybe to teach me how to control many webpages from a single one (index.php) and the others as templates. clicking the href include the form , and when you submit the action ="?" will strip the URL and send the variable "joketext" from the textarea to execute the sql query :)

Answer (score 1):

Personally don't ever do that.... Use `action="action.php"` or use `action=""` post to the current URL.

Not sure what you are trying to accomplish with `?` in the action attribute.

Comment: What '?' would accomplish is the URI the form is posted to would just be the page the form is displayed on.

Comment: @Popnoodles so why not just leave it blank or take it out? Just wondering.

Comment: Leaving it blank and taking it out are the same thing, neither of which are a good idea. See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1131781/is-it-a-good-practice-to-use-an-empty-url-for-a-html-forms-action-attribute-a

Comment: @Popnoodles ahh... so this question really is irrelevant because the OP is actually doing it correctly?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure if it's correct to do that. Why wouldn't you put `action="#"` to also preserve any GET vars? ...Not that I mix them. I always point to a file.

Comment: @Popnoodles Same, I'm going to have to look into it :) haha

Answer (score 0):

"We" don't and "You" shouldn't do so either.

- If you want to POST the data to the current URL, leave it empty, i.e. `action=""`.
- If you want to POST to another URL, put that URL in there, e.g. `action="save.php"`.

Comment: If you want to post to current url, `action=""` can be left out too.

Comment: Is that valid HTML? Edit: OK, in [HTML5 it is](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9401521/is-action-really-required-on-forms).

Comment: This leaves your form open to iframe clickjacking attacks. Also W3C says action is required not implied.

Comment: @Popnoodles: Any information on the clickjacking part?

Comment: Leaving action empty is also against HTML5 spec.

Comment: @Popnoodles: Obviously I meant in relation to this case. I know what Clickjacking in general is. I just don't see how it applies to this case.