# Specify no action parameter in @helper.form

Tags: playframework-2.0

Hi I have just started learning Play Framework 2.
Is it possible to not specify any action in the parameter of `@helper.form` in the scala template.
Something like:

```
@helper.form()
```

instead of

```
@helper.form(action=@routes.Apllication.create)
```

I want to make an Ajax call when a user presses enter in a form, rather than calling an action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@helper.form(action){...}` just generates HTML's `<form>` tag with proper `action` and `method` attributes basing on the routes defined.

That means, that you can just write the code yourself instead of using the helper.

```
<form id="myAjaxDrivenForm">
   <input type="text" name="foo" />
</form>
```

Comment: Of course you should take HTML specification into account about `action` attribute: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9401608/1066240