# When I press submit this form doesn't do anything

Tags: php, html

I have a problem, when I press submit in this form it doesn't do anything.

Its suposed to work because its code from a CMS, its the basic template.

If you need to look at my files i put here my skype to send you team viewer id and pass: javichuskater

You can see the error here: http://javiphp.byethost9.com/

This is the entire code of the index of the CMS:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="Get Free Bitcoins and Shatoshis Instantly From Our Faucet Online  Gana Bitcoins Gratis Instantaneamente Desde Nuestra Faucet">
    <meta name="author" content="BTCS4Free.Com">
    <meta name="keywords" content="Ganar dinero, Bitcoins Gratis, Bitcoin, RPG Bitcoin, What is Bitcoin, Free Bitcoin, Bitcoin Faucet, Free Coin, Free Cryptocurrency, Fast Bitcoins, FaucetBox Faucet" />
    <style>#l3c3{position:fixed!important;position:absolute;top:2px;top:expression((t=document.documentElement.scrollTop?document.documentElement.scrollTop:document.body.scrollTop)+"px");left:-2px;width:106%;height:104%;background-color:#FFCE85;opacity:.95;filter:alpha(opacity=95);display:block;padding:20% 0}#l3c3 *{text-align:center;margin:0 auto;display:block;filter:none;font:bold 14px Verdana,Arial,sans-serif;text-decoration:none}#l3c3~*{display:none}</style>
    <div id="l3c3"><span>Please enable JavaScript!<br><a href="http://google.com" target="_blank">[ BTCS4Free Webmaster ]</a></span></div><script>window.document.getElementById("l3c3").parentNode.removeChild(window.document.getElementById("l3c3"));(function(l,m){function n(a){a&&l3c3.nextFunction()}var h=l.document,p=["i","s","u"];n.prototype={rand:function(a){return Math.floor(Math.random()*a)},getElementBy:function(a,b){return a?h.getElementById(a):h.getElementsByTagName(b)},getStyle:function(a){var b=h.defaultView;return b&&b.getComputedStyle?b.getComputedStyle(a,null):a.currentStyle},deferExecution:function(a){setTimeout(a,2E3)},insert:function(a,b){var e=h.createElement("span"),d=h.body,c=d.childNodes.length,g=d.style,f=0,k=0;if("l3c3"==b){e.setAttribute("id",b);g.margin=g.padding=0;g.height="100%";for(c=this.rand(c);f<c;f++)1==d.childNodes[f].nodeType&&(k=Math.max(k,parseFloat(this.getStyle(d.childNodes[f]).zIndex)||0));k&&(e.style.zIndex=k+1);c++}e.innerHTML=a;d.insertBefore(e,d.childNodes[c-1])},displayMessage:function(a){var b=this;a="abisuq".charAt(b.rand(5));b.insert("<"+a+'><div class="well text-center" style="width:50%"><b>AD BLOCK DETECTED<br /><br />Please disable it for this site and reload the page.</b><br />BTCS4Free Faucet depends on the revenue from displaying adverts.</div> <a href="http://btcs4free.com" target="_blank">[ BTCS4Free Webmaster ]</a>'+("</"+a+">"),"l3c3");h.addEventListener&&b.deferExecution(function(){b.getElementBy("l3c3").addEventListener("DOMNodeRemoved",function(){b.displayMessage()},!1)})},i:function(){for(var a="SponsorsAds,adBlock01,ads-300-250,bott_ad2,dlads,ifmSocAd,toptextad,ad,ads,adsense".split(","),b=a.length,e="",d=this,c=0,g="abisuq".charAt(d.rand(5));c<b;c++)d.getElementBy(a[c])||(e+="<"+g+' id="'+a[c]+'"></'+g+">");d.insert(e);d.deferExecution(function(){for(c=0;c<b;c++)if(null==d.getElementBy(a[c]).offsetParent||"none"==d.getStyle(d.getElementBy(a[c])).display)return d.displayMessage("#"+a[c]+"("+c+")");d.nextFunction()})},s:function(){var a={'pagead2.googlesyndic':'google_ad_client','js.adscale.de/getads':'adscale_slot_id','get.mirando.de/miran':'adPlaceId'},b=this,e=b.getElementBy(0,"script"),d=e.length-1,c,g,f,k;h.write=null;for(h.writeln=null;0<=d;--d)if(c=e[d].src.substr(7,20),a[c]!==m){f=h.createElement("script");f.type="text/javascript";f.src=e[d].src;g=a[c];l[g]=m;f.onload=f.onreadystatechange=function(){k=this;l[g]!==m||k.readyState&&"loaded"!==k.readyState&&"complete"!==k.readyState||(l[g]=f.onload=f.onreadystatechange=null,e[0].parentNode.removeChild(f))};e[0].parentNode.insertBefore(f,e[0]);b.deferExecution(function(){if(l[g]===m)return b.displayMessage(f.src);b.nextFunction()});return}b.nextFunction()},u:function(){var a="-ad1.,/ad-choices-,/ads620x60/ad,/adstop728.,/adtest/ad,/custom/ads,/layer-advert-,/public/ads/ad,/pubmatic_,/728x90b/ad".split(","),b=this,e=b.getElementBy(0,"img"),d,c;e[0]!==m&&e[0].src!==m&&(d=new Image,d.onload=function(){c=this;c.onload=null;c.onerror=function(){p=null;b.displayMessage(c.src)};c.src=e[0].src+"#"+a.join("")},d.src=e[0].src);b.deferExecution(function(){b.nextFunction()})},nextFunction:function(){var a=p[0];a!==m&&(p.shift(),this[a]())}};l.l3c3=l3c3=new n;h.addEventListener?l.addEventListener("load",n,!1):l.attachEvent("onload",n)})(window);</script>

    <title>BTCS4Free - FreeBitcoins Instantly!</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS - Uses Bootswatch Flatly Theme: http://bootswatch.com/flatly/ -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="css/freelancer.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom Fonts -->
    <link href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700,400italic,700italic" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>

<body id="page-top" class="index">

    <!-- Navigation -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header page-scroll">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#page-top">BTCS4Free.Com</a>
            </div>

            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li class="hidden">
                        <a href="#page-top"></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="page-scroll">
                        <a href="#faucet">Faucet</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="page-scroll">
                        <a href="#about">About</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="page-scroll">
                        <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav>

    <!-- Header -->
    <header>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="img/profile.png" alt="">
                    <div class="intro-text">
                        <span class="name">BTCS4Freep</span>
                        <hr class="star-light">
                        <span class="skills">Free BitCoins instantly!</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>

    <!-- Portfolio Grid Section -->
    <section id="faucet">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                    <h2>Faucet</h2>
                    <hr class="star-primary">

    <div id="left">
        <ul>
        <?php foreach($data["user_pages"] as $page): ?>
            <li><a href="?p=<?php echo $page["url_name"]; ?>"><?php echo $page["name"]; ?></a></li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
        <?php echo $data["custom_left_ad_slot"]; ?>
        <p>Possible rewards: <?php echo $data["rewards"]; ?></p>
    </div>
        <div id="center">
        <h1><?php echo $data["name"]; ?></h1>
        <h2><?php echo $data["short"]; ?></h2>
        <p>Balance: <?php echo $data["balance"]." ".$data["unit"]; ?></p>
        <?php if($data["error"]) echo $data["error"]; ?>
        <?php switch($data["page"]): 
                case "disabled": ?>
            FAUCET DISABLED. Go to <a href="?p=admin">admin page</a> and fill all required data!
        <?php break; case "paid":
                echo $data["paid"];
              break; case "eligible": ?>
            <form method="POST" role="form">
                <div>
                    <?php if(!$data["captcha_valid"]): ?>
                    <p class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">Invalid Captcha!</p>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </div>
                <div>
                <label for="address">Your address:</label> <input type="text" name="address" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $data["address"]; ?>">
                </div>
                <div>
                    <?php echo $data["captcha"]; ?>
                    <div class="text-center">
                    <?php
                    if (count($data['captcha_info']['available']) > 1) {
                        foreach ($data['captcha_info']['available'] as $c) {
                            if ($c == $data['captcha_info']['selected']) {
                                echo '<b>' .$c. '</b> ';
                            } else {
                                echo '<a href="?cc='.$c.'">'.$c.'</a> ';
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" value="Get reward!">
                </div>
            </form>
        <?php break; case "visit_later": ?>
            <p>You have to wait <?php echo $data["time_left"]; ?></p>
        <?php break; case "user_page": ?>
        <?php echo $data["user_page"]["html"]; ?>
        <?php break; endswitch; ?>
    </div>
    <div id="right">
        <?php echo $data["custom_right_ad_slot"]; ?>
        <?php if($data["referral"]): ?>
        <p>
        Referral commission: <?php echo $data["referral"]; ?>%<br>
        Reflink:<br>
        <code><?php echo $data["reflink"]; ?></code>
        </p>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
```

Thanks for your help and time!

Comment: What is supposed to happen? Your form action is empty.

Comment: may this help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9401521/is-action-really-required-on-forms

Comment: please edit your code. doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @Daan Its suposed to work because its a CMS

Comment: Try to disable javascript, maybe some script prevents form from submission

Comment: when you say "it doesn't do anything" -- do you mean it doesn't submit the form, or that it reloads the page without any effect? You haven't got any code that parses the $_POST data

Comment: @Eddy Look, try it here http://javiphp.byethost9.com/

Comment: You haven't given the submit button an action so it's not going to do anything!

Comment: this code run but ,does not any sense. please modify your code

Comment: I think with the code there is ok? Or more code is needed @ManojKushwaha

Comment: I see ads in the background. _Tempted to flag as spam_

Comment: @UniKitty There are no ads

Comment: @PedroBenitez "Free BitCoins instantly!". Just kidding. I know you want help.

Comment: "Its suposed to work because its a CMS" sounds like "it's supposed to work because a radio makes sound"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have checked the link you have provided `http://javiphp.byethost9.com/`. it fires an ajax call to 'http://javiphp.byethost9.com/mail/contact_me.php' and return the response as 'No arguments Provided!'.

[image: screenshot]

Ajax call is made by this script file `<script src="js/contact_me.js"></script>`

I think, it is stopping further proccess.

Comment: How can i use the contact and the get reward at the same time?