# Firefox/PHP: cannot send password fields

Tags: php, html, firefox, passwords

It seems that Firefox (v 39.0) cannot send a form via http if the form contains a field of type password.
After submitting the following form Firefox clears the page and stops execution of the page. Firebug shows status code 200
for this post and no erros or warnings. In Chrome the script works as expected.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Password Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php 
    echo '<pre>Post-Data: '; print_r($_POST); echo '</pre>';

    if (isset($_POST['password'])) { 
        echo '<div>Password is: ' . $_POST['password'] . '</div>'; 
    }
    ?>

    <form action="./" method="post">
    Password: <input name="password" type="password" placeholder="Password">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I guess it's some security restriction. And I know that I should use https for password forms, but this is a decision of my boss.
So, how can I change this Firefox behaviour?

Comment: Could try making the form action PHP_SELF.

Comment: What is your original form action, is it really `./`? You should put the name of the target page there, ideally it is an absolute URL.

Comment: Oddly enough it works as anticipated with`action=""` though this is not recommended. It does also work as per martinstoeckli's method.

Comment: Using `./` as an action means to fetch the index file in the current folder your form is executed in. If your form isn't `index.php` then that could be an issue here. Use `action=""` for "self" as in the current file.

Comment: Try `<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) ?>">`

Comment: Again, perhaps oddly, the spec for html4 says action="" can be used but in html5 the spec says action= should be left out altogether if it is not specified as a valid url ...but it still does seem to work. Interesting background http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9401521/is-action-really-required-on-forms

Comment: Please use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your code and I believe your `action` to be wrong and should be just `action="?"`

Comment: `action="?"` - ? I'd do more like `action=""`. Why the question mark?

Comment: Returns your current path

Answer (score 0):

Ok, Problem was not the action attribute. I started Firefox with a new profile and now the script works fine. But I'm not sure which setting in the old profile caused the issue.