# How to save changed fields with ModelForm?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I want to save changed values of ModelForm to database. I'm having problems even I follow this documentation if I'm right that it can be possible with initial values: [Documentation- providing initial values](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#providing-initial-values)

**models.py:**

```
class Settings(models.Model):
   url = models.URLField(max_length=100, default='https://website.com')
   maxCount = models.SmallIntegerField(default=30)
```

**views.py:**

```
def Settings(request):

    settingsObj = Settings.objects.get(id=1)
    form = SettingsForm(initial={'url': settingsObj.url, 'maxCount':settingsObj.maxCount}, instance=settingsObj)

    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
```

**forms.py:**

```
class SettingsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Settings
        fields = ['url', 'maxCount']
```

**templates**

```
    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-6">
    {{ form.as_p }}
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="form-group">        
      <div class="col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-6">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Accept</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
```

Currently the form is showing the current values from database, but isn't saving changed data. form.is_valid() returns True, but form.save() seems to do nothing.

Comment: I didn't see any problem there

Comment: I get shown the values when I remove "request.POST" when I call the form at "form = SettingsForm(), but if I now change field values, they aren't saved to the database.

Comment: I don't see an `action` attribute in your `form` tag.

Comment: @YashTewari I don't want that the user is redirected away from the current site. It isn't the problem. Now I can see the values when the form is rendered, but the ModelForm isn't saving changed data.

Comment: Just [pointing this out](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9401608/6492916) to ensure it isn't the reason behind your problems. It probably isn't.

Comment: Add a `print` statement under `if form.is_valid():` to test if the flow ever reaches that point?

Comment: @YashTewari Now the form.is_valid() returns True when I changed `form = SettingsForm(initial={'url': settingsObj.url, 'maxCount':settingsObj.maxCount}, instance=settingsObj)`, but the form isn't still saved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `initial` argument and the `instance` argument in your call to `SettingsForm()` serve the exact same purpose, because you are using the fields of the `instance` individually in each field of `initial`.

The save() method is not working because you need to populate the form with data from `request.POST`.

This view should work:

```
def settings(request):    
    settingsObj = Settings.objects.get(id=1)
    if request.POST:
        form = SettingsForm(request.POST, instance=settingsObj)    
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
    else:
        form = SettingsForm(instance=settingsObj)

    context = { ..., 'form': form, ... }
    return render(request, 'template-address', context)
```

Comment: This works, but I can get only the url value to field, when the form is rendered. The maxCount-field is empty, when it has a value in database. Why is that?