# HTML tag form without "action" attribute

Tags: html

I'm using this HTML code in an HTML page:

```
<form method="post">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password">
  </div>
  <input type="hidden" name="ref" value="post-ad.php"/>
  <button type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="btn">S'identifier</button>
</form>
```

On clicking submit button which action will this form execute? I noticed that it execute the value of input named `"ref"` in this example `"post-ad.php"` or `"index.php"` or `"dashboard.php"`. Is it normal?! As I know the action attribute is mandatory?

Comment: without an `action` attribute it will POST/GET to the same page dependant upon `method`. The `action` is not mandatory

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1131781/is-it-a-good-practice-to-use-an-empty-url-for-a-html-forms-action-attribute-a

Without the action attribute the current page is used.

your field named ref is just like a normal input so the value will be available in $_POST['ref'] as a string.

Answer (score 3):

without action attribute it will `POST/GET` to the same page
[see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9401521/is-action-really-required-on-forms)

Answer (score 2):

If I understood right you're asking about action attribute that goes inside `<form>`.

If you put nothing there, it'll send the POST to the same page it is right now. If that form is in "index.php" it'll send all `<form>` data to "index.php"

Answer (score 0):

You call form without action with this code:

```
<form action="javascript:void(0);"></form>
```