# How to submit form without reloading?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Submit form without page reloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2866063/submit-form-without-page-reloading)

Hi I need to submit a form without reloading, how can I do this with javascript or frames?

Thanks

Comment: 1) Ajax. 2) Add `iframe` with name `frameName` and set `target="frameName"` attribute to form.

Comment: You can use the following jquery plugin: https://github.com/jinujd/jQuery-Async-Form

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this using jQuery: http://jquery.com/

Its a javascript framework and one of the methods you can use to do this kind of thing is:

```
$('#formID').submit(function(){

    var ajaxURL = '/ajax/saveAccountSettings.php';

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: ajaxURL,
        data: { 
            username: $('#accountForm #username').val()
        },
        success: function(data){

                        //Do something

        }
    });

    return false;

});
```

Probably worth reading up how to use jquery first though...

Comment: Thanks! Is it hard to learn though? kind of new to web stuff...

Comment: Hey, No it's actually pretty easy once you get the hang of the concept, jquery is pretty epic, can do a lot more than just this. Just read through the documentation and you'll get the jist of what you can do with it

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend JavaScript over trying to do anything with iframes. What you are looking for is XHRRequest, Simplest solution would be to use [JQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). I was going write up a quick example, but [this tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/submit-a-form-without-page-refresh-using-jquery/) seems to cover the steps pretty good.

Comment: Thanks will definetly check it out!

Answer (score 0):

You could use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) and the [jQuery Form Plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/).

jQuery Form Plugin's `ajaxForm` function enables you to "hijack" a form in your HTML. Consider this example:

```
<html> 
<head> 
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.js"></script> 
    <script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script> 

    <script> 
        // wait for the DOM to be loaded 
        $(document).ready(function() { 
            // bind 'myForm' and provide a simple callback function 
            $('#myForm').ajaxForm(function() { 
                alert("Thank you for your comment!"); 
            }); 
        }); 
    </script> 
</head>
<body>
    <form id="myForm" action="comment.php" method="post"> 
    Name: <input type="text" name="name" /> 
    Comment: <textarea name="comment"></textarea> 
    <input type="submit" value="Submit Comment" /> 
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

See the plugin's website for more info. It supports various callback functions for error handling etc.