# Preventing from redirect after clicking on link in iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've got the following code:

```
<iframe>
...
  <form id="formId" action="someurl">
  </form>
  <a href="#" onclick="$('#formId').submit(); return false;">click</a>
...
</iframe>
```

I want to submit the form by clicking on link BUT to stay on the same page (not to redirect). I've tried `$(document).on('click', 'a', false);` with no luck.

Comment: You can use AJAX for this action. Here you have similar topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18169933/submit-form-without-reloading-page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the answers seem correct, but actually that's not what helped out me in the end. In my particular sitation, I wanted to download a file when user clicks on the link inside iframe. After clicking on the link, form has been submitted and the ajax request has been sent to my method in controller. It turned out, that if I implement a method correctly to send some data to user, iframe won't redirect. Initially I'd been testing this redirection behaviour on empty method in controller which caused the problem - which suprises me a little.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('a').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#formId').submit();

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try to set the iframe to and sandboxed one. Then you can use prorerty's like:

sandbox="..."

- allow-forms allows form submission
- allow-popups allows popups
- allow-pointer-lock allows pointer lock
- allow-same-origin allows the document to maintain its origin
- allow-scripts allows JavaScript execution, and also allows features
  to trigger automatically
- allow-top-navigation allows the document to break out of the frame by
  navigating the top-level window

Link: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/sandboxed-iframes/

```
<iframe sandbox="allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-popups allow-forms" src="http://www.example.com"</iframe>
```

Answer (score 1):

Submit form with `ajax` to stay on current page.

```
var $form = $("#formId");

// register handler for submit first
$form.submit(function (event) {
    $.ajax({
        type: $form.attr("method"),
        url: $form.attr("action"),
        data: $form.serialize()
    })
    .done(function (data) {   

    })
    .fail(function (r, s, e) {

    });

    event.preventDefault();
});

// and then submit the form
$form.submit();
```

[More about jQuery submit()](https://api.jquery.com/submit/)