# How to use form.submit() in javascript to save a form without reloading the page

Tags: jquery, forms

I have two save buttons on the form. One is `save and reload`, the other one is `save and stay on the page`.

When the user clicks save and stay on the page I want it to save and not to refresh the page.

```
var form = $("#frmSaveAction");
```

I am currently using this to submit.

```
form.submit()
```

Comment: Then what is the issue its not working ?

Comment: Use AJAX. There are literally *thousands* of questions and tutorials on how to do this

Comment: I think this question has been discussed already  here   see this one : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18169933/submit-form-without-reloading-page

Comment: @MujthabaIbrahim which itself is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2866063/submit-form-without-page-reloading

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Submit form without page reloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2866063/submit-form-without-page-reloading)

Answer (score 1):

Submit The Form Without Page Refresh Using Ajax And jQuery

please refer this url : http://talkerscode.com/webtricks/submit%20the%20form%20without%20page%20refresh%20using%20ajax%20and%20jquery.php

Comment: I think this is a kind of comment, isn't it ?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers

Comment: [answer] *Provide context for links. Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.*