# PHP - Post to Self without refreshing (Or another alternative)

Tags: javascript, php, html, post, refresh

Good evening SO community,

I'm trying to build a global chat system for my network of websites. In other words, a staff member can log in to www.myadminswebsite.com and check the live chat systems from all of our other external sites. I have the system working fairly well, except for the fact that the page is refreshing every time a user submits a new message. Is there something I can do to avoid refreshing the page to submit a message? Currently, I'm using an HTML form which posts to itself, then the page checks to see if the $_POST["var"] exists, then writes to the IM log file.

**Code From HTML Form**

```
<form method='POST' action='" . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . "'>
    <input type='text' name='newMSG' id='lcTextInput' placeholder='Type a Message'>
    <input type='submit' value='Send'>
</form>
```

**Function to Process POST**

```
if (isset($_POST['newMSG'])) {
    $wHandle = fopen($lFile, "a");
    fwrite($wHandle, "[CUSTOMER] " . $_POST['newMSG'] . "\n");
    fclose($wHandle);
}
```

This does what I need it to do, other than refreshing the page. Please let me know if you need any more information or if you have any ideas!

Thanks in advance,

Tim

Comment: Did you check this link ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2866063/submit-form-without-page-reloading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<form> 
<input type='text' name='newMSG' id='lcTextInput' placeholder='Type a Message'>
    <input type='submit' value='Send' id="submit">

</form>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$('#submit').click(function()
{
var message=$("#lcTextInput").val();
    $.ajax({
        url: "msg.php", 
        type:'POST',
        data:
        {
            action: 'addmsg',
            message: message
        },
        success: function(msg)
        {
            $(".li").append(message);
        }               
    });

return false;
});

</script>
```

Comment: You have to make submit type as a button or on the basis of action you have to save value into the database

Comment: Can this be done without a submit button? For example, the user just hits enter?

Comment: Unfortunately, this is still refreshing my page.

Comment: Use a `<button>` element instead of an actual Submit button, you can bind the Enter key to it and call the ajax function

Comment: hi please remove form now then try

Comment: @NishantSaini What do you mean. remove form?

Comment: @TimothyBomer check my below code i have added new code run that

Comment: @TimothyBomer checked ?

Answer (score 0):

Change your form action to:

```
<form method='POST' action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
    <input type='text' name='newMSG' id='lcTextInput' placeholder='Type a Message'>
    <input type='submit' value='Send'>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. This bit of code is already withing a PHP Echo statement, which is why it is formatted like it is in the above code, omitting the <?php ?> and echo statements.

Comment: Ah my bad. Should have assumed that

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#submit').click(function()
{
var message=$("#lcTextInput").val();
    $.ajax({
        url: "msg.php", 
        type:'POST',
        data:
        {
            action: 'addmsg',
            message: message
        },
        success: function(msg)
        {
            $(".li").append(message);
        }               
    });

return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form> 
<input type='text' name='newMSG' id='lcTextInput' placeholder='Type a Message'>
    <input type='submit' value='Send' id="submit">

</form>
```

Comment: @Hitesh yes this is working fine you have to add check it in your system

Comment: Thanks, I will check in system!!! Since you shared code snippet, I thought it should work there as well