# Avoid page refresh caused by postback in asp.net without AJAX

Tags: asp.net, download, httpresponse, postback, page-refresh

I know there are lots of similar questions, but a tricky idea has come to my mind.

It is known that a download `HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment")` can stop the browser from refreshing page, because a download itself is a response and a refreshed page cannot be generated as another response. Of course I'm not going to make a download just to get rid of page refresh, but I'm thinking of if there is any other form of HTTP response that can 'replace' the page refresh, or any method of `HttpContext.Current.Response` that can clear the default response. Any idea?

(Don't ask me why it has to be without AJAX. I know it can work. Just not preferred at the moment)

Comment: I think you need to give a bit more background on what you are trying to achieve here. You want the browser to send the POST request, but you don't want to get the response..?

Comment: @user1429080 I'm doing task scheduling stuff for download. As nothing is updated due to the submission, no page refresh is intended. In addition, I have another option which is to download immediately. I would like to make two options consistent in whether refresh or not refresh. I can generate a refresh for immediate download by `setTimeout`, but it's not preferred either because the time required is unknown (it might be long). Therefore, I am now looking for a refresh prevention for scheduled download.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just discovered the iframe way.

[Submit form without page reloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2866063/submit-form-without-page-reloading)

Not what I expected for, but in the same direction which I have been looking for, though a 'meaningless' element needs to be created.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have to send data in `POST` body, then you can utilize an `image` object and just set it's `src` to the server URL, this will execute the code on server and will NOT refresh our page. It's kinda AJAX but NOT in a regular way.

Following is an example JS code

```
function execute_test_method_on_server(param1, param2) {
    var u = "/api/somecontroller/test_get_method?param1=" + param1 + "&param2=" + param2;
    (new Image).src = u;
    return true;
}
```