# How to submit data without reloading page?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I have been trying to solve this problem for a long long time. I'm new to web developing. What I'm trying to do is that when I'm click to submit button for submitting the values, the page should remains to it's position, but instead it's automatically goes to top, which I don't want that.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
   <style>
   .bigbox{
    height: 600px;
    width: 500px;
    background: olive;
    margin: 10px;
}
   </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="bigbox">1</div>
<div class="bigbox">2</div>
<h4>type the range of numbers:</h4>
    <form id="myform">
            <input type="text" name="num1" placeholder="num1">
            <input type="text" name="num2" placeholder="num2">
            <button type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">Submit</button>
            <button type="reset">Reset</button>
    </form>
    <?php
        if(isset($_GET['submit']))
        {
            $num1=$_GET['num1']; 
            $num2=$_GET['num2'];
            $prefix=array("st","nd","rd","th");
         for($j = $num1 ; $j<=$num2;$j++)
         {
             switch($j)
             {
                 case ( $j%100==11 || $j%100==12 || $j%100==13 ); $i=3; break;
                 case $j%10==1: $i=0;break;
                 case $j%10==2; $i=1;break;
                 case $j%10==3; $i=2;break;
                 default : $i=3;
             }
             echo "this is the ".$j.$prefix[$i]." number "."<br>";
         } 
        } 
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Instead of actually submitting the form, you should look into what's called AJAX. AJAX is the general term for "sending data to a server without going to a new page or reloading the current page". It can be done with libraries like jQuery, or native JavaScript with the older XMLHttpRequest class or the newer fetch() function.

Comment: It's worth noting that your page isn't actually "reloading," but rather a new request is being served which includes your form data inside of `$_GET`. Hopefully, this detail will help with your understanding of how server-side code works, going forward.

Comment: Like @IceMetalPunk said, you should use AJAX. Your current code doesn't work because your php is executed when the page is loaded, so submitting the form won't do anything.

Comment: @lucky Because StackOverflow is a place to help people learn, not to write code for you. I gave you not only the name of the technique you need, but 3 different ways you can do it. Google exists: use it. If, after Googling the things I mentioned and trying it yourself, you still can't get it working, then feel free to post your new AJAX-based code here and we can help you fix whatever's not working with it.

Comment: @IceMetalPunk thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Submit form without page reloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2866063/submit-form-without-page-reloading)

Answer (score 2):

I have created [a pen](https://codepen.io/psyNiiM/pen/BaaRKzB) with the closest approach to solve such problem,
To achieve this using javascript [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API)

```
 const formElement= document.getElementById("myform");
 formElement.addEventListener('submit',(e)=>{
   e.preventDefault();
   const formData = new FormData(formElement);
   fetch(`api/url`, {
     method: 'POST',
     body: formData,
   })
   .then(result  => result .json())
   .then(data=> console.log(data)) //after form submit
   .catch((err)=>console.log(err));
});
```

The [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) interface provides a way to easily construct a set of key/value pairs representing form fields and their values.

For browser compatibility of fetch API check [This link](https://caniuse.com/#search=fetch).

Comment: okay, I changed type "submit" to "button", and also add the javaScript part but its not working for me, can you please repost my code with your solution, that will save my day?

Comment: @niiima This code won't do anything. All it's doing is stopping the form from submitting normally, and then submitting the form. It will result in exactly the same behavior as a normal submission, except it won't trigger when you press Enter. That's not what the OP is trying to do.

Comment: @IceMetalPunk I edit my answer and create a real example of how using fetch with form data, I believe this is a solution to the question.

Comment: `new new FormData` ? the first `new` is just to make sure? ;)

Comment: Thanks for mentioning it, I have edit my answer, while I was laughing! @RokoC.Buljan

Comment: `()=>event.preventDefault()` should be `event=>event.preventDefault()`

Comment: Also please don't use `$submit` -> it's not a jQuery Object. Use rather `el_submit` to point out that it's a DOM Node Element

Comment: Also you should do your fetch logic **inside the form submit function** (right after the e.preventDefault() thing), not inside a button click. So `formElement.addEventListener('submit',(e)=> {e.preventDefault(); /*FETCH HERE*/ });` is all you need.

Comment: Your Codepen code does not reflect the code in your answer :)

Comment: I've update [code pen](https://codepen.io/psyNiiM/pen/vYYZQML)  too with promise base fake API call and invoked the require logic inside `submit` event handler. Thank you again for the guidance on the comments that let me correct my answer. @RokoC.Buljan