# Server response is printed on the browser but not returned to success function in ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am not able to get the response to ajax success call back function. The response form the server is being directly printed on the browser

```
<body>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $.ajax({
          url: $("#form").attr("action"),
          type: "POST",
          data: $("#form").serialize(),
          success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
          }
        });
      });
    </script>
    <form action="a.php" method="post" id="form">
      <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="name" />
      <input type="submit" value="submit" />
    </form>
  </body>
```

my php code

```
<?php
    echo 'hii';
?>
```

Comment: check this answer this might help you. [Submitting Form Without Reloading The Page And Get Result Of Submitted Data In The Same Page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49376645/3903073)

Comment: use echo json_encode($return); or use dataType: "text", in ajax

Comment: the problem with echo is that may be whitespace or other echos also cause, which will cause issue when you want to read response, so try to return json

Comment: I am still facing the same problem.<?php
    echo json_encode('hii');
?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you Replace AJAX script below mentioned.

```
<form method="post" id="form">
  <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="name" />
  <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>

 $("#form").submit(function(e) {

    e.preventDefault(); // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.

    var form = $(this);
    var url = form.attr('action');

    $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: 'a.php',
           data: form.serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
           success: function(data)
           {
               alert(data); // show response from the php script.
           }
         });
});
```