# How to submit form without reload page

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I have form action with textarea and submit button

```
<form method="post" action="/analyze">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="text">Input text:</label>
            <textarea class="w-100" name="text" id="text" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group d-flex justify-content-center">
            <input type="submit" class="btn__submit btn btn-dark my-auto" value="Обработать">
        </div>
    </form>


    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <p th:text="#{nertext}"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

When I click submit button, i want to get processed text from server in Spring Boot and paste in tag p in div col.
    Java Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/analyze", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String analyzeText(@RequestParam String text, Model model) {
    System.out.print(classifier.classifyToString(text, "tsv", false));
    String asd = classifier.classifyToString(text, "tsv", false);

    model.addAttribute("nertext", asd);

    return "/analyze";
}
```

How can i do submit without reload page

Comment: With using JavaScript.

Comment: Search for AJAX.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Submit form without page reloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2866063/submit-form-without-page-reloading)

Answer (score 1):

Use the Fetch API (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) and the `onsubmit` event listener (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onsubmit) to submit the form with JavaScript without reloading the page:

```
let form = document.getElementById("the-form");
form.onsubmit = function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    fetch(form.action, {
        method: "post", 
        body: new FormData(form)
    }).then(response => {
        // do something with the response...
    });
}
```

The `e.preventDefault()` makes sure that the page is not reloaded when you click the submit button. This assumes your form has the id `the-form`, like this:

```
<form id="the-form" method="post" action="/analyze"> ... </form>
```

Comment: I think he should implement event.preventDefault() in his function call