# Submit form without reload

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

i have problem, i want to click button and submit form and button change from OPEN to CLOSE. and it works  but the main problem when the page reload the open value changes to close after click and return back to open value
so i wanted to make my page not to reload so when i click button open and goes to close without turning back to open. its like i want to prevent page reload after form submit, main issue prevent page reload after submit so that button remain on close value after click

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>asdsadsad</title>

</head>
<form id="form" action="test.html" method="post">
<input onclick="ClickMethod()" type="button" value="Open" id="myButton1">
</form>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function ClickMethod() {

  document.getElementById("myButton1").value="Close";
  document.getElementById("form").submit();
}
var frm = $('#form');
    frm.submit(function (ev) {
        $.ajax({
            type: frm.attr('method'),
            url: frm.attr('action'),
            data: frm.serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
                alert('ok');
            }
        });

        ev.preventDefault();
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you need to use `return false` instead of `ev.preventDefault()` explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/event-preventdefault-vs-return-false

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Submit form without page reloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2866063/submit-form-without-page-reloading)

Comment: no sir. it don't

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Your Title</title>
</head>
<form id="form" method="post" action="test.html">
<input onclick="ClickMethod()" type="button" value="Open" id="myButton1">
</form>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function ClickMethod() {
  document.getElementById("myButton1").value="Close";
  var frm = $('#form');
  $.ajax({
            type: frm.attr('method'),
            url: frm.attr('action'),
            data: frm.serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
                alert('ok');
            }
        });
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: yes bro thats wat i need, but its not submitting only changing button name, i even added method="post" but not submitting