# How to prevent scrolling caused by clicking a link with the #-Extension (in PHP)

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

At first: I'm working with HTML and PHP, so please no tips for js. I built a website that shows some data. It's much longer than one screen size, so i created a href=" #down" and href=" #up" link at the beginning and end of the page with the corresponding div-containers (with the ID #up and #down). At the end of the page, I also have some buttons like show temperature (for example). These buttons are linked to a post function that reads and echos the temperature at the top of the website. But: if I clicked on the down-link, there is an extension at the web address like "../index.php#down". So when i click the "show temperature" button, it displays the temperature at the top, but the website is still scrolled down because of this hashtag. Before I added them, I had to scroll down all the time, but at least the presentation jumped to the top again when I clicked the Button. I know there are some solutions with JS, but I have the question, if it is possible to remove the "#down"-extension by clicking the $post-linked Button (either while clicking the Button or in the executed post-function). Thanks a lot :)!

#### Edit:

Added my code:

```php
<html> Header, Title, etc.
 <?php
 echo '<br><a href="#down">&#8595; Scoll down &#8595;</a></p>';
 if (isset($_POST['tempNow']))
    {
         echo '<p>The temperatuere right now is: [<span style="color:Tomato">';
         echo shell_exec('head -n 1 /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp | xargs -I{} awk "BEGIN {printf \"%.2f\n\", {}/1000}"');
    echo ' C</span>], Systemtime: ' . shell_exec('date');
    echo '.</p>';
    }?>



*** LONG LISTE OF DATA ON THE WEBSIDE***
<form method="post">
   <p>


    <button name="tempNow">Show temp. right now</button>

</p>

</form>

<a href="#">&#8593; Scroll up &#8593;</a>
<div id="down"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Does this help? When i click to the Scroll-Down, it adds "#down" to my URL. Now, when i am clicking the button, it reloads, adds the Temperature at the top, but because there is still "#down" added to the URL, the view stays scrolled down at the bottom of the webside.

ps.: Maybe i have to mention: for scrolling up, its enough to add a "#" in the href. But i guess you all allready know that.

Comment: Buttons don't do anything (excluding submit buttons) without script. Maybe you have links, i.e. `a` elements? Also, instead of describing your code only, you could post the code itself to the question, that would be much easier to understand.

Comment: Please share more details, like the code involved. Also, how are PHP and CSS related to this?

Comment: okay sure, give me a second, i will add the code above

Comment: You should probably title the question based on the actual problem you have, not the thing you believe to be its cause. Sounds like a case of [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/302323)

Comment: I cant edit the Question, dont know why, so i have to add the code down below, i hope it helps. I tried to find the right title, i also allready did some research but cant find a solution to this problem.

Comment: And yeah, sorry, should be named: how to remove...., sorry! cant change it right know, dk why.

Comment: "I cant edit the Question" - what does that mean? You were able to add the information to the question that you could not edit it, so why not add all the rest?

Comment: i found hte error: i had to accept an editing from another person first but it didn´t show this option to me, now it works, i will edit and reup clearer later

Answer (score 1):

> So when i click the "show temperature"-button, it displays the
> temperature at the top, but the webside is still scrolled down because
> of this hashtag

To avoid the website from scrolling down when you click the "Show temperature" button, wrap the button in a hyperlink with the `id` attribute similar to the button itself.

```html
<a href="#show-temp"><button name="tempNow" id="show-temp">Show temp. right now</button></a>
```

##### Addendum

If the "show temperature" button is submitting a form, this may be interesting to you:

[Submit form without page reloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2866063/submit-form-without-page-reloading)

Comment: I tried to do this, but id did not work, either it only activates the [a href] (when wrapped in between the button) or it only executed the button...

Comment: @OscarDonnerstag if you want to prevent scrolling say that, was hard to decode your question ;-) (my deleted answer shows how to modify URL, each time hash-link is clicked, but did not prevent scrolling)

Comment: @OscarDonnerstag Try some of the solutions in the resource link of my answer.