# Display express.js res.send() without overwriting current html

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

I am trying to create a calculator app using express.js to get request for an html file and a post request that takes the user's input and responds with the answer. However, I want to display my answer inside a html container without the page redirecting. Is there a way to achieve this with vanilla javascript?

index.html

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="#" />
    <title>Calculator</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Calculator App</h1>
    <form action="/" method="post" class="ajax">
      <label for="userInput">Enter Equation</label>
      <input type="text" id="equation" name="equation" />
      <button type="submit" id="btn_submit">Calculate</button>
    </form>
    <div class="container"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
const express = require('express'); 
const app = express();
port = 3000;

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended : false }));
app.use(express.static('public'));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + public);
});

app.post('/', (req, res) => {
    let equation = req.body.equation;
    console.log(equation);
    let result = eval(equation);
    res.status(200).send('Result is ' + result);
    
});

app.listen(port, ()=> {
    console.log('Hosted on port: ' + port);
});
```

[CalculatorApp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/84fX0.png)
[Evaluated Expression](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XvJ4T.png)

Comment: I think you want AJAX--make a fetch call with JS, prevent the default form action (navigation) and put the response data back into the DOM.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Submit form without page reloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2866063/submit-form-without-page-reloading)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to write front end JavaScript code to make the ajax request instead of having the form action submit the request. The JavaScript will receive the response and can update the value on the HTML.

```
app.post('/', (req, res) => {
    let equation = req.body.equation;
    console.log(equation);
    let result = eval(equation);
    res.status(200).json({ value: `Result is ${result}` });
    
});

<script>  

 document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit',submitEquation);

    
        function submitEquation(event){
            event.preventDefault();
             const input = document.querySelector('#equation');
             const equation = input.value;
             const clearInput = true;
             if(clearInput){
                input.textContent = '';
             }
             fetch(window.location.origin, { 
                method: 'post', 
                body: JSON.stringify({ equation }) 
             })
             .then(response => response.json())
             .then(json => {
                  document.querySelector('.container').textContent = json.value;
             })
          }
</script>
```