# I want the innerHTML of my tag to be updated with the input value

Tags: javascript, html, forms, innerhtml, innertext

```js
const paragraph = document.querySelector(".paragraph")
const input = document.querySelector("input")

const updInnerHTML = () => {
paragraph.innerHTML = input.value
}
```

```html
  <form>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Type Something">
    <button onclick="updInnerHTML()">Update InnerHTML</button>
  </form>
  
  <p class="paragraph"></p>
```

The above code seems to work for a split second, the value appends to the `<p>` tag and vanishes immediately, Yeah I know this could be made permanent if I remove `<form></form>` tags, but then I'll lose the ability to automatically clear the input fields! Is there a work around for this? Do I need to use a database or atleast LocalStorage? Is there a way to achieve it without using a database?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Submit form without page reloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2866063/submit-form-without-page-reloading)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `action="javascript:void(0);"` for no form submit and then clear form by `input.value ='';`

```js
const paragraph = document.querySelector(".paragraph")
const input = document.querySelector("input")

const updInnerHTML = () => {
paragraph.innerHTML = input.value;
input.value ='';
}
```

```html
<form action="javascript:void(0);">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Type Something">
    <button onclick="updInnerHTML()">Update InnerHTML</button>
  </form>
  
  <p class="paragraph"></p>
```

Comment: So I basically should code for each individual value in case I have a fairly large form with many input fields?

Answer (score 0):

Because the `button` will submit the `form` which will make the page reload, you can prevent that by setting `type="button"` to the button element ( type of button by default is `submit` ).

```js
const paragraph = document.querySelector(".paragraph")
const input = document.querySelector("input")

const updInnerHTML = () => {
paragraph.innerHTML = input.value
}
```

```html
<form>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Type Something">
    <button onclick="updInnerHTML()" type="button">Update InnerHTML</button>
  </form>
  
  <p class="paragraph"></p>
```